React. How to change state of component with static functions?
I need to change state of my Modal component, whith static function.
I need a similar component, for example, in the ant.design library
Modal.confirm({});

but I want to implement my functionality without using antd.
const App = () => {
return (
 <div className="app">
    <button 
       onClick={() => {
          Modal.show({
             title: 'Hello', 
             onOk: (ids) => console.log('ok', ids), 
             onCancel:() => console.log('cancel')
          }); // Shows modal with some content
     }}>
     Show Modal
   </button>
 </div>
)
}

How can i do this?
interface ModalProps {
    title?: string
    okButtonText?: string
    onOk?: (data?: any) => void
    onCancel?: () => void

}

const Modal: React.FC & { show: (props: ModalProps) => void } = (props) => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
    
     const handleOk = () => {
       if(props.onOk){props.onOk([1,2,3]);}
     }

    return (
           <div className={visible ? 'modal-open' : ''}>
              <p>Some text...</p>
              <Button onClick={handleOk}>Save</Button>
            </div>
     );
}

Modal.show = ({ okButtonText = 'Save', title, onCancel, onOk }: ModalProps) => {
    const showModal = () => {
        // How to change state of modal? setVisible(true);
    }
    return showModal();
}


This is not how it is implemented at antd most probably. Firstly would suggest against writing something like this. You are writing imperative commands whereas React is declarative. Prefer to do these rendering from your cyclic state itself

Even if you want something like this, please remember that if you add a method like show to Modal it is common for all invocations of Modal.
To make something like this work Modal.show should again have some logic which will update some state, which inturn will toggle view of modal from some portal.

There is a workaround to do that with the useContent
First, manage your state in a context like
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const ModalContext = createContext();

const ModalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [modalProps, setModalProps] = useState({ visible: false });

    const showModal = (props) => {
        setModalProps({ ...props, visible: true });
    };

    const hideModal = () => {
        setModalProps({ visible: false });
    };

    return (
        <ModalContext.Provider value={{ ...modalProps, showModal, hideModal }}>
            {children}
        </ModalContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { ModalProvider, ModalContext };

Update your Modal component with the use of that context
const Modal = () => {
    const { visible, title, okButtonText, onOk, onCancel, hideModal } = useContext(ModalContext);

    const handleOk = () => {
        if (onOk) onOk([1, 2, 3]);
        hideModal();
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        if (onCancel) onCancel();
        hideModal();
    };

    if (!visible) return null;

    return (
        <div className='modal'>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <p>Some text...</p>
            <button onClick={handleOk}>{okButtonText || 'Save'}</button>
            <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    );
};

Then define the static show method.
const useModal = () => useContext(ModalContext);

Modal.show = (props) => {
    const modal = useModal();
    modal.showModal(props);
};

Now you can use Modal.show like
import { ModalProvider } from './ModalContext';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <ModalProvider>
            <div className="app">
                <button onClick={() => Modal.show({
                    title: 'Hello',
                    onOk: (ids) => console.log('ok', ids),
                    onCancel: () => console.log('cancel')
                })}>
                    Show Modal
                </button>
                <Modal />
            </div>
        </ModalProvider>
    );
};

